# 3.5mm audio switch/selector

Tags: audio, headset

I am looking for an audio switch for a 3.5mm headset. There seem to be tons of options (e.g. [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073GWCRP3)) for a normal 3.5mm stereo switch, but they all do not support microphones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like doing what you are looking for:

[**Nobsound Little Bear MC1023 2-Way Audio Microphone Headset Speaker MIC Switcher Headphone Switch Hub Volume Control Controller Selector 3.5mm RCA**](https://amzn.to/3a8rWuX)

Comment: Thats what I am looking for. Might go for the MC2014 as that seems to use 4 pole connectors.

Comment: @Mats, MC2014? Can you put a link?

Comment: From the same company [MC2014](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KS2KDWW/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_U_x_rsXhEb181Y4YE). Looks like same product, just with 4pole in-/output

Comment: Oh (was just not finding the model...), it's actually **MC1024**

Answer (score 0):

There's a large number of splitters/combiners for one to two 3.5mm Jack's available on the market. If you can't find a single switch then you might get a splitter, a combiner and two switches. While a bit of a kludge, this solution will work.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that and just have one switch with 4pole in/out.

Comment: Track down some decent audio relays and it suddenly turns into a nice DIY projects. Though it would probably end up costing 50$+ if you get it right on the first try.